# What does Integral of $d^2$ mean

Tags: calculus, integration, notation

I was going through the [Gravitation Lensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lensing_formalism) Wikipedia page and came across this formula: [image]

This notation of the Integral doesn't say anything to me.

Why is the expression after the $d$?

What does $d^2$ in this context mean?

Comment: This is common notation in physics to denote an area integral. Similarly $d^3 x$ or something similar denotes a volume integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$d^2\theta '$ means that you're integrating in two dimensions (it's a double integral, on both directions of $\theta'$.

Comment: Oh. Thank you very much.